# How can I generate screenshots via script?

Tags: android, screenshot

Is it possible to generate Screenshots for Android via a script?

The problem is: I have an app with 8 languages and I need to create new localized screenshots. Is there a tool to run it once for one language and then to regenerate the ecreenshots for the other languages?

Comment: Do you maybe have an update here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fastlane to generate the screenshot using espresso test.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/screenshots/

[image]

Comment: Only for Mac :(

Comment: Mac and debian based, are you on windows ?

Comment: It's been 3 years now. Is this still the answer you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Macro recorder for android, there's plenty of apps out there that can automate things.
Just record the actions for one language and play them again after selecting other languages.
Example apps:

[MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en)
[Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en)